# uikit вложенный accordion как?

Tags: uikit

Как сделать вложенный accordion на uikit?
Добавляю к секциям data-uk-accordion-1, data-uk-accordion-2... – не помогает.

Answer (score 0):

Вариант решения. Тут просто обертка, но можно в цикле с индексами сделать. Итак:

1. Ранее дописываем:

```js
<div class="uk-accordion" data-uk-accordion='{toggle:".ule", containers:".serg", showfirst: false}'>
```

2. Далее пишем так

```js
    <h3 class="uk-accordion-title ule">Заголовок</h3>
    <div class="uk-accordion-content serg">
        
        //это было, будут внутренними пунктами
        <div class="uk-accordion" data-uk-accordion>
            <h3 class="uk-accordion-title">Подзаголовок</h3>
            <div class="uk-accordion-content">
    
    //.... и т.д.
```